# Why am I getting an invalid argument error?

Tags: compiler-errors

Here's what I have for my declaration:

```
typedef enum { WHITE, BLACK } vcolor_t;
vector<vcolor_t> vcolor;
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
error: template argument for 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator' uses local type
      'citysim::dijkstra(std::vector<int>&, const int&, const int&)::vcolor_t'
error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator'
error: template argument 2 is invalid
error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
```

Whenever I make a declaration like

```
vcolor_t vcolor;
```

it doesn't give me any errors, so I don't understand why the vector declaration is giving me these errors.

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>`?

Comment: Yes, I have the vector library included.

Comment: Then try to use `std::vector<vcolor_t>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as it stands will compile on the MS compilers but not on gcc.  I don't really know the reason for this.  Move your typedef declaration out of the routine dijkstra and it should compile.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
namespace city
{
    typedef enum {WHITE, BLACK} vcolor_t; // <-- Move it here
    void dijkstra(...)
    {
        // typedef enum ...  <-- the compiler does not like this
        vector<vcolor_t> vcolor;
    }
}
```